# Intent not getting passed successfully! :(

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

Perhaps you will find the question that I'm going to ask to be too mainstream/basic. But I need help maybe I'm a newbie. 
  Basically I'm making a simple app that displays maps about some tourist places in an offline manner.It has three activities.
A - expandable list
B - activity that displays a map using a webview
C - TabHost that hosts the Activity B.

Whenever a child is clicked from the expandable list in the Activity A it sends two intents.
1) To Activity B giving the location of the desired map.
2) To Activity C to start the TabHost.
Code is as follows:

```
 if (childclicked=="Red Fort")
            {
                Intent toMap =  new Intent(TourList.this,Map.class);
                toMap.putExtra(ID , "file:///android_asset/redfort.jpg");

                Intent i = new Intent(TourList.this,TourTabs.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
```

and the code in the activity B is as follows:

```
public class Map extends Activity {
String imageUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);


    //Using a webview for pinch zooming
    WebView vw=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    vw.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);      

    //Fetching intents
    Intent fromList = getIntent();



  imageUrl = fromList.getStringExtra(TourList.ID);
   vw.loadUrl(imageUrl);
}
```

But the bug is runtime. Nothing gets displayed in the TabHost. The WebView does not display anything. Why? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed the value correctly in intent but i think you have started activity of second intent in which you are not passing anything and you are trying to access that value from the activity `TourList.ID` which has not passed there.

Try out as below and try to run the activity of `Map.java` and then access the value.

> ```
>  if (childclicked.equals("Red Fort"))
>   {
>      Intent toMap =  new Intent(TourList.this,Map.class);
>      toMap.putExtra(ID , "file:///android_asset/redfort.jpg");
>    startActivity(toMap);
>
>    Intent i = new Intent(TourList.this,TourTabs.class);
>     startActivity(i);
>
>  }
> ```

Also change the if condition according to i have done. 
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey glad for your reply! Unfortunately, it solved the problem partially. Now it opens both the activities separately. The map image gets displayed in `Map.class` successfully. But the TabHost is still displaying a blank WebView. Meaning Intents are getting transferred successfully but there's some problem with the TabHost only.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (childclicked=="Red Fort")
 {
    Intent toMap =  new Intent(TourList.this,Map.class);
    toMap.putExtra(ID , "file:///android_asset/redfort.jpg");

    Intent i = new Intent(TourList.this,TourTabs.class);
    startActivity(i);

 }
```

Strings can not be compared with `==` in java. You have to use equals or equalsIgnoreCase

```
 if (childclicked.equals("Red Fort"))
```

Inside the if body you create two different `Intent`. In one you put a string and use the other to start an Actvity. The first is useless

Comment: I'm glad for your reply! But the snippet of code you pointed out is working correctly. It's perfectly fine to compare strings using `==` operator in Java. Thanks.